# In scilab how do you plot sin as a curve rather than as straight lines?

Tags: charts

In scilab how do you plo sin as curve rather than as straight lines?

```
x=[0,90,180,270,360]
// sind is sin with argument of degrees. rather than radians.
// https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/sind.html
y=sind(x)
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

But I want something more like

[image]

i.e. a curve rather than straight lines.

Comment: What about using more points to draw the curve (increase x by 1, not 90)?

Comment: @MátéJuhász ah you're right `x=[0:1:360]`   Now I just wonder how to get the intersection of x=y=0

Comment: @MátéJuhász you can post your answer and I will accept it.  This works, increases by 1 up to 360.  `x=[0:1:360]`   (as for the x=y=0 thing i've taken it out of the question and will make a separate question for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have much more points to see the chart as a sin function, not just set off lines.

**Added by barlop**

like this

`x=[0:1:360]`

to increase from 0 to 360  in steps of 1

[image]